# Dealing with command line options in a typesafe manner, after parsing with JOpts

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, decoupling

When parsing options with the [JOpt Simple](https://jopt-simple.github.io/jopt-simple/index.html) library, the only way I know of accessing their respective types is by saving the OptionSpec instances somewhere and accessing them latter. For example:

```
OptionParser parser = new OptionParser();

ArgumentAcceptingOptionSpec<Path> pathOption = parser
    .acceptsAll(Arrays.asList("p", "path"),
        "Read message from a file")
    .withRequiredArg()
    .withValuesConvertedBy(new PathConverter());

/* We will use this one latter */
OptionSpec<Path> pathOptionSpec = pathOption;

OptionSet parsedOptions = parser.parse("-path", "./foo/bar");

/* 
See? Unless I missed something, you need the pathOptionSpec object
(which is of type OptionSpec<Path>) to retrieve the "path"'s option type.
 If I used .valueOf("path"), it would return 
an OptionSet<?> and I would have to typecast it!
*/
assertThat(
    parsedOptions.valueOf(pathOptionSpec),
    instanceOf(OptionSpec<Path>.class));
```

Now, what I did was saving the OptionParser, the OptionSet and every OptionSpec as static members of the Main class, and access those options from anywhere in the program (you may now screech and raise your pitchforks now).

- **Is there a clean way to manage parsed CLI arguments in a typesafe way?**